How to know what the "Layout default" keys are?
How can one view what the "Layout default" key bindings are?
In Ubuntu 23.10 Gnome (Xorg session) Settings: Keyboard: Compose Key & Alternate Characters Key are set to "Layout default".   How can I know what exactly those keys are?
